# Dynamic changing Variables in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

what I want to do is:
for example:

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {'x':'xxx','y':'xxx'}
        self.cla = [['B', self.d['x'], self.d['y']], ['C', self.d['x'], self.d['y']]]
```

As you can see, `self.cla` is a list contains two lists, what i want to do is if I change the `self.d['x']`, then all the parameters in `self.cla` which equal to `self.['d']` are changed at the same time. 
e.g.

```
self.d['x'] = 'abc'

# then, the result i want to get after changing is 
self.cla = [['B', 'abc', 'xxx'], ['C', 'abc', 'xxx']]
```

If I write the code in C++ 'version', it should be something like:

```
self.cla = [['B', &self.d['x'], &self.d['y']], ['C', self.d['x'], self.d['y']]]
```

so, after I changed `self.d['x']` to 'abcde' in `self.d`, the value in self.cla is `[['B', 'abcde', 'xxx'], ['C', 'abcde', 'xxx']]`

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: If you're using Python 2, you should probably use new-style classes and inherit from `object`: use `class a(object):` instead.

Comment: I would suggest using properties, *but*: the problem is you're not setting an attribute, you're setting a *key-value* of a dict attribute. Thus complicating things, since this happens related to the dict, not so much to the class instance (i.e., `self`).

Comment: Do you intend to change `self.cla` *only* through `self.d`, or also directly?

Comment: I intend to change self.cla by changing self.d, because as you can see, if i have thousands of items in self.cla, if i want to change all the variables which equals to self.d['x'] (or self.d['y'], self.d['x'] or blablabla or all of them)at the begining, it could be more convenient to just changing the value in self.d. If it is C++, i think i can store the address in self.cla

Answer (score 0):

Use a property for `cla`:

```
class A(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.d = {'x': 'xxx', 'y': 'xxx'}
            self._cla = self.cla

        @property
        def cla(self):
            self._cla = [['B', self.d['x'], self.d['y']],
                         ['C', self.d['x'], self.d['y']]]
            return self._cla

a = A()
print(a.cla)
a.d['x'] = 123
print(a.cla)
a.d['y'] = 'xyz'
print(a.cla)
```

This results in

```
[['B', 'xxx', 'xxx'], ['C', 'xxx', 'xxx']]
[['B', 123, 'xxx'], ['C', 123, 'xxx']]
[['B', 123, 'xyz'], ['C', 123, 'xyz']]
```

Don't try to set `a.cla` directory this way, however; then you would need to define a setter property as well.